# Is `ALTER TABLE mytable REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;` a safe operation for a high volume postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, postgresql-9.6, debezium

I am working with debezium and a Postgres database. The database contains several tables with TOAST (The Oversized-Attribute Storage Technique) columns. To handle unchanged Postgres TOAST column values, one approach is to set the `REPLICA IDENTITY` of a table to `FULL`. However, I am not sure if running `ALTER TABLE mytable REPLICA IDENTITY FULL` could cause downtime on the database or it will be a safe operation. The current value for `REPLICA IDENTITY` is `DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the replica identity will not cause down time, but it requires a short `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, which can be a problem if you have long running transactions that involve the table.

However, I don't see the point of the exercise.  This has nothing to do with TOAST; the only effect is that the replicated `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements will have all columns in the `WHERE` condition rather than just the primary key, which will increase the WAL volume and be bad for performance.

`REPLICA IDENTITY FULL` is mostly a crutch for tables without a primary key, which is to be avoided anyway.